# Making changes to files in node_modules, what is best practice?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js, node-modules

I have a VueJS project that uses Vuetify. I've created a web component that requires ShadowDOM and I've had to make a change to a single file in node_modules to make the Vuetify dialog work in ShadowDOM.

I got the fix from [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9056).

I'm aware that changing files in node_modules is not recommended but what is the best practice when a change/fix needs to be implemented such as my one?

Can a function within a file contained in node_modules be overridden?

Comment: You might use `yarn patch` (https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch)

Comment: `patch-package` works well for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: This may work for Vuetify but is a rabbit hole in general. Patching /dist is very fragile, it's safer to patch /src, but and not all deps provide /src (can be solved by installing a dep from git), and even if they do, it may be not easy to build it because a dep relies on its own config that may differ from your own. If you're able to build a dep, for options api components it may be more flexible to extend a component and replace some of its options (mixins, methods) to achieve the desirable result. Any way, for fixed dep version that isn't updated much, patch-package is the way

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give this package a try and see whether it solves my problem.